# How to document an enum case with parameters?

Tags: swift, enums, code-documentation

Given an `enum` that has a `case` with parameters, how can I document these parameters?

For example these code comments:

```
/// Various coffee types.
enum Coffee {

  /// A Cappuccino.
  /// - parameters:
  ///   - cream: Is true if cream is added.
  case cappuccino(cream: Bool)
}
```

produce this pop-up which is lacking the `cream` parameter documentation.

[image]

So what is the correct markup?

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed a duplicate. Hence should I delete this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/// Various coffee types.
enum Coffee {

    /// A Cappuccino.
    /// - cream: Is true if cream is added.
    case cappuccino(cream: Bool)
}
```

It'll show up as a bullet point when you click on `cappuccino` but won't show up if you click on the `cream` parameter.. But it's good enough I guess..